# Forward List Implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

NB: There's a bug with my iterator, apparently. I can't use `const_iterator` because I get some compiler errors. I know using `const` there is wrong, but I have to find a way to fix it first...

I finished implementing `std::vector` and decided to continue with `std::forward_list`.
This time, I did not take the time to make it "allocator aware", but opted for a more soft approach.
What I'm really interested in is memory leaks and the correctness of the logic behind the functions, since I have suffered a lot to implement some stuff, and I'm quite sure that I've done it the worst way.

```
#ifndef FORWARD_LIST
#define FORWARD_LIST

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <concepts>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace container{
    template<typename Type>
    class ForwardList {
    private:
        struct Node {
            Type data;
            Node* next;
            Node() = default;
            template<class... Args>
            constexpr explicit Node(Args&&... args) : data{ std::forward<Args>(args)... } {}
        };

        Node* m_head;
        Node* m_tail;
        std::size_t m_size{};       

        template<typename T>
        class forward_iterator {
        private:
            // Thanks to user Mooing Duck (from www.stackoverflow.com) for this simple alias fix (which solved code duplication for forward_iterator and its const version)
            Node* m_iterator;

        public:
            using value_type = T;
            using reference = T&;
            using pointer = value_type*;
            using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
            using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

            constexpr forward_iterator(Node* forw_iter = nullptr) : m_iterator{ forw_iter } {}

            constexpr Node* getNodeAddress() const noexcept { return m_iterator; }
            constexpr Node* getNodeNextAddress() const noexcept { return m_iterator->next; }
            constexpr reference operator*() const noexcept { return m_iterator->data; }
            constexpr pointer operator->() const noexcept { return m_iterator; }
            constexpr forward_iterator& operator++() noexcept {
                m_iterator = m_iterator->next;
                return *this;
            }
            constexpr forward_iterator operator++(int) noexcept {
                forward_iterator tmp(*this);
                m_iterator = m_iterator->next;
                return tmp;
            }
            constexpr friend bool operator== (const forward_iterator& first, const forward_iterator& second) noexcept { return (first.m_iterator == second.m_iterator); }
            constexpr friend bool operator!=(const forward_iterator& first, const forward_iterator& second) noexcept { return !(first.m_iterator == second.m_iterator); }
        };

        /* Useful functions for internal purposes */
        constexpr void deallocate(ForwardList& other) noexcept {
            if (!other.m_head) { return; }
            Node* current_node = other.m_head;
            while (current_node != nullptr) {
                Node* next_node = current_node->next;
                delete current_node;
                current_node = next_node;
            }
            other.m_head = nullptr;
            other.m_tail = nullptr;
            other.m_size = 0;
        }

    public:
        using value_type = Type;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using reference = value_type&;
        using const_reference = const value_type&;
        using pointer = Type*;
        using const_pointer = const pointer;
        using iterator = forward_iterator<value_type>;
        using const_iterator = forward_iterator<const Type>;

        // Member functions
        constexpr ForwardList() noexcept
            : m_head{ nullptr }
            , m_tail{ nullptr }
            , m_size{ 0 }
        {}
        
        constexpr explicit ForwardList(size_type count, const_reference value)
            : m_size{ count } {
            Node* current_node = new Node(value);
            m_head = current_node;
            for (size_type index{ 0 }; index < count - 1; ++index) {
                current_node->next = new Node(value);
                current_node = current_node->next;
            }
            m_tail = current_node;
            m_tail->next = nullptr;
        }

        // Type must be DefaultConstructible 
        constexpr explicit ForwardList(size_type count)
            : ForwardList(count, Type{})
        {}
        
        template<std::input_iterator input_iter>
        constexpr ForwardList(input_iter first, input_iter last)
            : m_size{ static_cast<size_type>(std::distance(first, last)) } {
            Node* current_node = new Node(*first);
            m_head = current_node;
            for (size_type index{ 0 }; index < m_size - 1; ++index) {
                current_node->next = new Node(*(++first));
                current_node = current_node->next;
            }
            m_tail = current_node;
            m_tail->next = nullptr;
        }

        constexpr ForwardList(const ForwardList& other) {
            if (other.m_head) {
                m_size = other.m_size;
                Node* current_node = new Node(other.m_head->data);
                Node* current_other_node = other.m_head;
                m_head = current_node;
                while (current_other_node->next != nullptr) {
                    current_node->next = new Node(current_other_node->next->data);
                    current_node = current_node->next;
                    current_other_node = current_other_node->next;
                }
                m_tail = current_node;
                m_tail->next = nullptr;
            }
            else {
                ForwardList();
            }
        }

        constexpr ForwardList(ForwardList&& other) noexcept
            : ForwardList() {
            other.swap(*this);
        }

        constexpr ForwardList(std::initializer_list<Type> list)
            : m_size{ list.size() } {
            Node* current_node = new Node(*(list.begin()));
            m_head = current_node;

            for (auto it = list.begin() + 1; it != list.end(); ++it) {
                current_node->next = new Node(*it);
                current_node = current_node->next;
            }
            m_tail = current_node;
            m_tail->next = nullptr;
        }
        
        ~ForwardList() {
            Node* current_node = m_head;
            while (current_node != nullptr) {
                Node* next_node = current_node->next;
                delete current_node;
                current_node = next_node;
            }
            m_head = nullptr;
        }
        
        constexpr ForwardList& operator=(const ForwardList& other) {
            ForwardList temp_list(other);
            temp_list.swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }

        constexpr ForwardList& operator=(ForwardList&& other) noexcept {
            other.swap(*this);
            deallocate(other);
            return *this;
        }

        constexpr ForwardList& operator=(std::initializer_list<Type> list) {
            ForwardList temp_list{ list };
            temp_list.swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }

        constexpr void assign(size_type new_size, const_reference value) {
            deallocate(*this);
            ForwardList temp_list(new_size, value);
            temp_list.swap(*this);
        }

        constexpr void assign(std::initializer_list<Type> list) {
            deallocate(*this);
            ForwardList temp_list{ list };
            temp_list.swap(*this);
        }

        template<typename input_iter>
        constexpr void assign(input_iter first, input_iter last) {
            deallocate(*this);
            ForwardList temp_list(first, last);
            temp_list.swap(*this);
        } 

        // Element access
        constexpr reference front() noexcept {
            return m_head->data;
        }
        
        constexpr const_reference front() const noexcept {
            return m_head->data;
        }

        // Iterators
        constexpr iterator begin() noexcept {
            return iterator(m_head);
        }

        constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept {
            return const_iterator(m_head);
        }

        constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept {
            return const_iterator(m_head);
        }

        constexpr iterator end() noexcept {
            if (m_tail == nullptr) { return nullptr; }
            return iterator(m_tail->next);
        }

        constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept {
            if (m_tail == nullptr) { return nullptr; }
            return const_iterator(m_tail->next);
        }

        constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept {
            if (m_tail == nullptr) { return nullptr; }
            return const_iterator(m_tail->next);
        }

        constexpr bool empty() const noexcept {
            return m_size == 0;
        }

        constexpr size_type size() const noexcept {
            return m_size;
        }

        constexpr size_type max_size() const noexcept {
            return std::numeric_limits<difference_type>::max();
        }

        //Modifiers
        constexpr void clear() noexcept {
            deallocate(*this);
        }

        template<typename...Args>
        constexpr iterator emplace_after(const iterator position, Args...args) { // Must be O(1)
            Node* temp = position.getNodeAddress();
            Node* current_node = new Node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            if (temp == m_tail) {
                m_tail->next = current_node;
                current_node->next = nullptr;
                m_tail = m_tail->next;
            }
            else {
                Node* next_temp = position.getNodeNextAddress();
                temp->next = current_node;
                current_node->next = next_temp;
            }

            m_size += 1;
            return iterator(current_node);
        }

        constexpr iterator insert_after(const iterator position, const_reference value) {
            return emplace_after(position, value);
        }

        constexpr iterator insert_after(const iterator position, Type&& value) {
            return emplace_after(position, std::move(value));
        }

        constexpr iterator insert_after(const iterator position, size_type count, const_reference value) {
            iterator temp;
            for (size_type i{ 0 }; i < count; ++i) {
                temp = emplace_after(position, value);
            }
            return (count == 0) ? position : temp;
        }

        constexpr iterator insert_after(const iterator position, std::initializer_list<Type> list) {
            iterator temp;
            for (auto current : list) {
                temp = emplace_after(position, current);
            }
            return (list.size() == 0) ? position : temp;
        }

        constexpr iterator erase_after(const iterator position) {
            Node* temp = position.getNodeAddress();
            Node* next_temp = temp->next;
            if (temp!=nullptr && next_temp->next == nullptr) {
                temp->next = nullptr;
            }
            else if (temp != nullptr) {
                temp->next = next_temp->next;
                delete next_temp;
            }
            m_size -= 1;
            auto pos = position;
            return (++pos != nullptr) ? pos : end();
        }

        constexpr iterator erase_after(iterator first, iterator last) {
            Node* firstNode_temp = first.getNodeAddress();
            Node* firstNode_next = first.getNodeNextAddress();
            Node* lastNode_temp = last.getNodeAddress();

            while (firstNode_next != lastNode_temp) {
                Node* temp = firstNode_next->next;
                delete firstNode_next;
                firstNode_next = temp;
                --m_size;
            }
            firstNode_temp->next = lastNode_temp;

            return last;
        }

        constexpr void push_front(const_reference value) {
            emplace_front(value);
        }

        constexpr void push_front(Type&& value) {
            emplace_front(std::move(value));
        }

        template<typename...Args>
        constexpr reference emplace_front(Args...args) {
            Node* head_temp = m_head;
            Node* current = new Node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            m_head = current;
            m_head->next = head_temp;
            ++m_size;
            return m_head->data;
        }

        constexpr void pop_front() {
            Node* head_temp = m_head;
            Node* next_temp = m_head->next;
            m_head = next_temp;
            delete head_temp;
            --m_size;
        }

        constexpr void resize(size_type count, const_reference value=Type()) {
            if (count < size()) { 
                Node* tmp = m_head;
                for (size_type index{ 0 }; index < count-1; ++index) { 
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
                Node* other_tmp = tmp;
                tmp = tmp->next;
                while (tmp->next != m_tail){
                    Node* tmpp = tmp->next;
                    delete tmp;
                    tmp = tmpp;
                }
                delete m_tail;
                m_tail = other_tmp;
                m_tail->next = nullptr;
            }

            else {
                Node* temp_tail = m_tail;
                for (size_type index{ 0 }; index < count; ++index) {
                    temp_tail->next = new Node(value);
                    temp_tail = temp_tail->next;
                }
                m_tail = temp_tail;
                m_tail->next = nullptr;
                temp_tail = nullptr;
            }
        m_size = count;

        }
        
        constexpr void swap(ForwardList& other) noexcept {
            Node* temp_node;
            temp_node = m_head;
            m_head = other.m_head;
            other.m_head = temp_node;
            temp_node = nullptr;

            Node* temp_tail;
            temp_tail = m_tail;
            m_tail = other.m_tail;
            other.m_tail = temp_tail;
            temp_tail = nullptr;

            std::swap(m_size, other.m_size);
        }

        constexpr void splice_after(const iterator position, ForwardList& other) {
            Node* current_pos = position.getNodeAddress();
            if (current_pos == m_tail) {
                m_tail->next = other.m_head;
                m_tail = other.m_tail;
            }
            else {
                Node* next_node = position.getNodeNextAddress();
                Node* next_next = next_node->next;
                Node* temp_head = other.m_head;
                Node* temp_tail = other.m_tail;

                current_pos->next = temp_head;
                temp_tail->next = next_next;
            }
            m_size += other.m_size;
            other.m_size = 0;
            other.m_head = nullptr;
            other.m_tail = nullptr;
        }

    private:
        constexpr Node* _Remove(Node* beforeNode) noexcept { // Bug->Last element not removed/crash
            const auto to_remove = beforeNode->next;
            const auto removed_next = to_remove->next;
            beforeNode->next = removed_next;

            delete to_remove;
            return removed_next;
        }

    public:
        constexpr size_type remove(const_reference toRemove_value) {
            return remove_if([&toRemove_value](auto other) { return other == toRemove_value; });
        }

        template<typename Predicate>
        constexpr size_type remove_if(Predicate pred){ 
            Node* before_begin = new Node(); 
            Node* tmp_before_begin = before_begin;
            before_begin->next = m_head;
            size_type tot_removed{ 0 };

            for (Node* first = m_head; first != nullptr;) {
                if (pred(first->data)) { // Lambda is true, remove the element - m_head might be changed
                    if (first == m_head) {
                        first = _Remove(before_begin);
                        m_head = first;
                    }
                    else {
                        first = _Remove(before_begin);
                    }
                    ++tot_removed;
                }
                
                else { // m_head is not removed
                    before_begin = first; 
                    first = first->next;
                }
            }
            
            delete tmp_before_begin;
            m_size -= tot_removed;
            return tot_removed;
        }

        constexpr size_type unique() {
            size_type removed{ 0 };
            for (Node* first = m_head; first != nullptr;) {
                if (first == m_tail) break;
                if (first->data == first->next->data) {
                    first = _Remove(first);
                    ++removed;
                }
                else {
                    first = first->next;
                }
            }
            m_size -= removed;
            return removed;
        }
        
        constexpr void reverse() noexcept {
            Node* temp_data = m_head;
            ForwardList temp = ForwardList();
            while (temp_data != nullptr) {
                temp.push_front(temp_data->data);
                temp_data = temp_data->next;
            }           
            temp.swap(*this);
        }

    private:
            /*Example taken from geeksforgeeks*/
            constexpr void _Sort(Node* (&head_ref), Node* new_node) {
                Node* current;
                if (head_ref == nullptr || (head_ref)->data >= new_node->data) {
                    new_node->next = head_ref;
                    head_ref = new_node;
                }
                else {
                    current = head_ref;
                    while (current->next != nullptr && current->next->data < new_node->data) {
                        current = current->next;
                    }
                    new_node->next = current->next;
                    current->next = new_node;
                }
            }

    public:
        constexpr void sort() {
            Node* sorted = nullptr;
            Node* current = m_head;
            while (current != nullptr) {
                Node* next = current->next;
                _Sort(sorted, current);
                current = next;
            }
            m_head = sorted;
        }       

        constexpr bool operator<=(const ForwardList<Type>& other) {
            return !(other < *this);
        }

        constexpr bool operator >=(const ForwardList<Type>& other) {
            return !(*this < other);
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool operator== (const ForwardList<T>& first, const ForwardList<T>& other) {
        auto temp = first.m_head;
        bool notEqual = false;
        if (first.size() != other.size()) return false; 
        else{
            while (temp != nullptr) {
                if (!(temp->data == other->data)) {
                    notEqual = true;
                    break;
                }
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        return notEqual == true ? false : true;
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool operator!= (const ForwardList<T>& first, const ForwardList<T>& other) {
        return !(first == other);
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<(const ForwardList<T>& first, const ForwardList<T>& other) {
        return (std::lexicographical_compare(first.begin(), first.end(), other.begin(), other.end()));
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>(const ForwardList<T>& first, const ForwardList<T>& other) {
        return !(std::lexicographical_compare(first.begin(), first.end(), other.begin(), other.end()));
    }

}

#endif
```

Comment: Does posted code run and execute as expected. If it doesn't compile, then it doesn't run and is off-topic for code review.

Comment: It should run fine. The "NB" in the beginning is just to tell that if I change the current iterator to const_iterator, it will not work.

Comment: I checked, and it doesn’t compile. But it appears to be just a couple of typos. 1) In the `ForwardList(size_type, const_reference)` constructor, you have `new Node<Type>`… but `Node` is not a template. 2) In the `ForwardList` `operator<=`, the `return` is missing. With those two fixes, it *appears* to work, at a very cursory check. But really, you should check these things yourself, and more, by writing some simple tests. You should ***ALWAYS*** write tests, maybe even before the actual code itself.

Comment: Thanks, indi. For some reason it happened to work on VS2019. Fixed those two issues now. I guess I edited some stuff and forgot to re-test, so thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Yeah, because it’s a template, compilers are *technically* not obligated to check it for correctness (other than syntactic correctness) it until it’s instantiated, so VS is *technically* not wrong to pass it (until you actually try to instantiate the problematic functions, then boom). On the other hand, when it’s obvious it can *never* be correct no matter what type it’s instantiated with, it’s nice to get a diagnostic, so kudos to GCC for that. But again, you should really write tests for all new code… ideally before the actual code. It’s *really* worth it.

Comment: `using const_pointer = const pointer;` is also wrong. Have you seen https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/01/const-iterator-antipatterns/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls/8054856 ?

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion More often than not there are cases where your code would compile with MSVC but throw errors on other compilers like GCC, and the opposite. The good thing to do is to test on multiple to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry don't have time for a comprehensive review:

### Code Review

Some nits:

What happens when `count == 0`

```
    constexpr explicit ForwardList(size_type count, const_reference value)
```

---

What happens when `first == last`

```
    constexpr ForwardList(input_iter first, input_iter last)
```

---

You have a constructor that takes iterators. Why does the list version not reuse this:

```
    constexpr ForwardList(std::initializer_list<Type> list)
         // Could forward the call to the list iterator.
         : ForwardList(std::begin(list), std::end(list))
```

---

Overall there is a lot of repeated code in your constructors. I am pretty sure you can **DRY** this up a lot.

---

Comment: Ah, pity. I was planning to do a thorough review on the weekend. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks for the review nonetheless. I'm currently reviewing the whole implementation and trying to remove all the duplicates.